# Using VS Code Extentions for VS Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community for years (Now VS2019). But recently it is getting harder to find new extensions for Visual Studio Community because most recent extensions are developed for Visual Studio Code.
I want to know if there is any way to install and use VS Code Extensions on VS Community?
And why they are totally different?
Can I convert VS Code extension to a VS Community compatible one?